# Junction Object or Comma separated values

Tags: custom-object, data

Customer has a table in their legacy application where one of the fields have comma separated values of customer Ids. CustomerId could exist on multiple of these records. So there is Many to Many relationship.

Customer Id is external id on Account in Salesforce. Wondering when we migrate this table to salesforce should we continue to use comma separated values or create a Junction object between this new migrated table and Account.

Junction object seems cleaner. However comma separated values have the advantage of performance as the code need not traverse relationships. Please let me know your thoughts.

Thanks.

Comment: I would still opt for junction objects for the following reasons:
 much easier to track / report on the data, can add automation processes if required, more readable and user friendly on the UI

Comment: Agree with Vishal.  You also won't have data integrity issues if the comma separated values is somehow corrupted